# Get the number of boosts in a server discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a server info command and I want it to display the server name, boost count, boost members and some other stuff as well.

Only problem is I have looked at the docs and searched online and I cant find out how to find the boost information.

I dont have any code as Ive not found any code to try and use for myself

Is there any way to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guild Name - `guild_object.name`

Boost count - `guild_object.premium_subscription_count`

Boosters, the people who boosted the server - `guild_object.premium_subscribers`

If your doing this in a command as I assume, use `ctx.guild` instead of `guild_object`. For anything further, you can re-read the docs as all of the above information is in it under the `discord.Guild`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.command()
async def boostcount(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f'{ctx.guild.name}\'s Boost Count', description = f'{str(ctx.guild.premium_subscription_count)}')
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```